# Can multiple cuda kernels execute in parallel on the same SM?

Tags: cuda, cuda-streams

Suppose a cuda gpu with just one SM.

Can I start two cuda kernels in parallel that use say 512 threads? Or are kernels assigned in blocks, causing the kernels to be executed in series rather than in parallel, thus idling the remaining 512 cores for both executions?

I tried finding documentation describing the scheduling mechanisms behind nvidia gpus, but I could only find documentation that described how a single kernel gets resources allocated to it. It did not state if two kernels could be assigned to a single block in parallel, or if resources are allocated at a warp level, or maybe even a thread level.

I expect either block level or warp level resource sharing, but I'd like to understand the actual scheduling algorithms rather than guess, or reverse engineer.

Comment: This question might make more sense if you replace the word "block" with "SM". A block is not a piece of hardware. It is by definition specific to a certain kernel launch. But the question if two blocks from different kernels can run on the same SM in parallel is valid.

Comment: See [CUDA C++ Programming Guide: Concurrent Kernel Execution](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#concurrent-kernel-execution) for some information although it doesn't answer the question of sharing an SM.

Comment: Nvidia GPUs have many SM. Each SM can execute multiple blocks (AFAIK possibly multiple block simultaneously). A block can AFAIK only be executed by 1 SM. Thus, with a kernel of 1 block, only 1 SM can be used which is clearly sub-optimal. Same for too blocks. Modern GPUs have AFAIK dozens of SMs. Note that the two blocks can be executed on 2 different SM but AFAIK they may run on the same (regarding how the scheduler actually behave). To fully use a GPU at its full capacity, you generally need to submit a kernel with at least 2-4 blocks per SM (i.e. typically hundreds of blocks).

Comment: By the way, the way blocks are scheduled to SM is AFAIK dependent of the target device so you need to focus on one (set of) specific architecture (and specify this in your post). Besides, it is not clear what "resources" actually means in your post.

Comment: To avoid confusion: The concept of the "SM" or "multiprocessor" is introduced in [CUDA C++ Programmin Guide: A Scalable Programming Model](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#a-scalable-programming-model). It is clear that (given enough resources like registers and shared memory) multiple blocks from the same kernel launch can run on the same SM concurrently. For different kernels or even different grids/launches of the same kernel function I don't know if this holds true.

Comment: Thank you all for clearing up the distinction between block and SM. That might explain a lot. So suppose I have two kernels launched at the same time, say in different streams. Each uses 512 threads. I have 1024 cuda cores. If I have 2 SM's in my GPU it seems obvious that they run concurrently. But what if I have a cuda gpu with 1SM and 1024 cuda cores, can both kernels use 512 cores in parallel?

Comment: Yes, even on a single SM, it is possible for the block scheduler to deposit blocks from two different kernels.  My suggestion would be to not focus on CUDA cores for this.

Comment: AFAIK, yes (especially on modern architectures, but maybe not on old ones). This is also dependent of the exact kernel code. For example, a block can request soo much shared memory that the other block will not be able to run simultaneously on the same SM because of the limited shared memory space. I am not aware of any Nvidia GPU having only 2 SM since at least 10 years.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I don't think OP has a GPU with only 1 or 2 SMs. The question is still interesting. One could e.g. run one long-running kernel that uses all shared memory on all SMs and one or multiple short kernels not using any shared memory that run concurrently on all SMs avoiding under-utilization of compute units due to block synchronization in the first kernel.

Comment: @paleonix Ok. I agree, though it would be better if the OP would ask this explicitly rather than a theoretical example (which is not efficient). I wanted to point out that it is better to increase the number of blocks in each kernel if possible so to saturate SMs. GPUs can have a lot of SM so running few kernel in parallel is often not enough to fully take advantage of their computing power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've lightly edited the question so that it is more-or-less sensible, and does not conflate software hierarchy (blocks) with hardware hierarchy (SMs, cuda cores, etc.)  The comment stream clarifies OPs acknowledgement, in my view.

Yes, even on a single SM, it is possible for the block scheduler to deposit blocks from two different kernels.

Here is an example/test case:

```
$ /usr/local/cuda/samples/bin/x86_64/linux/release/deviceQuery
/usr/local/cuda/samples/bin/x86_64/linux/release/deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "Quadro K610M"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          11.4 / 11.4
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.5
  Total amount of global memory:                 981 MBytes (1028784128 bytes)
  (001) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:    192 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            954 MHz (0.95 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             1300 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              64-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 524288 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total shared memory per multiprocessor:        49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device supports Managed Memory:                Yes
  Device supports Compute Preemption:            No
  Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            No
  Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      No
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 11.4, CUDA Runtime Version = 11.4, NumDevs = 1
Result = PASS
$ cat t37.cu
#include <iostream>
__device__ volatile int s = 0;
__global__ void k1(){
  while (s == 0) {};
}
__global__ void k2(){
  s = 1;
}

int main(){

  cudaStream_t s1, s2;
  cudaStreamCreate(&s1);
  cudaStreamCreate(&s2);
  k1<<<1,1,0,s1>>>();
  k2<<<1,1,0,s2>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
  if (err != cudaSuccess) std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t37 t37.cu -arch=sm_35
nvcc warning : The 'compute_35', 'compute_37', 'compute_50', 'sm_35', 'sm_37' and 'sm_50' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
$ ./t37
$
```

This is on a laptop with a Quadro K610M.  `deviceQuery` shows us that this GPU has a single SM.

The test code shows two kernels.  The first launched kernel (`k1`) will spin forever until the global location (`s`) becomes non-zero.  The second launched kernel (`k2`) sets the global location to non-zero, allowing the first kernel to exit.  The net result is normal application termination.  If the two kernels were not scheduled at the same time, on the same SM (there is only 1) then the first kernel would spin forever, the second would never run, and the observed application behavior would be a hang.  (You can witness a hang for example by launching both kernels into the same stream, eg. the default NULL stream.)

The fact that we do not see a hang means that both kernels ran at the same time, on the same SM.

There are a number of other questions here on the `cuda` SO tag which discuss block scheduling, and GPU scheduling behavior.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624793/warp-and-block-scheduling-in-cuda-what-exactly-happens-and-questions-about-el/64624926#64624926) is one example.  There are others.

EDIT: Responding to a question in the comments, here is a test case that tries to find how many kernels can run "at once" on this single SM GPU:

```
$ cat t37.cu
#include <iostream>
#ifndef NL
#define NL 8
#endif
const int num_launches = NL;
__device__ volatile int s = 0;
__global__ void k(){
  atomicAdd((int *)(&s), 1);
  while (s < num_launches) {};
}

int main(){
  std::cout << "Number of kernels: " << num_launches << std::endl;
  cudaStream_t s[num_launches];
  for (int i = 0; i < num_launches; i++) cudaStreamCreate(s+i);
  for (int i = 0; i < num_launches; i++) k<<<1,1,0,s[i]>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
  if (err != cudaSuccess) std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t37 t37.cu -arch=sm_35 -DNL=16
nvcc warning : The 'compute_35', 'compute_37', 'compute_50', 'sm_35', 'sm_37' and 'sm_50' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
$ ./t37
Number of kernels: 16
$
```

The above test case is successful for 16 kernels.  If I compile instead with `-DNL=32` the test case hangs.  Referring to [table 15 in the CUDA 11.4 programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.4.0/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability), there are several relevant numbers for this cc3.5 GPU:

> Maximum number of resident grids per device:   32

> Maximum number of resident blocks per SM:  16

So we seem to have confirmed that if we go beyond 16 kernels, then we have exceeded the 16 blocks per SM limit, and the code will hang.

Comment: Great answer! If I can ask one more follow up question: is it possible to look up how many kernels can run on a single SM?

Comment: I don't know that that has its own specification anywhere, however there is a specification for the maximum number of kernels that can be simultaneously running on the device as a whole, in one of the tables in the CUDA programming guide. From [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#concurrent-kernel-execution): "The maximum number of kernel launches that a device can execute concurrently depends on its compute capability and is listed in Table 18." So its upper-bounded by that as well as the maximum number of warps per SM, since a kernel has at least 1 warp.

Comment: I've added another test case to my answer.  The relevant limit appears to be blocks per SM, limiting "kernels per SM" in this case.